# how to tell the joystick is changing direction

Tags: flame

I want my player is able to change clothes if the joystick direction is changed, I mean if
for now is `gameRef.joystick.direction` is `JoystickDirection.right` the player is moving right, otherwise player is moving left, but the clothes on the player can not tell the moment when the player direction is changed.
I tried to use such method:

```
  bool moveLeft = false;
  bool moveRight = false;
  bool moveTop = false;
  bool moveDown = false;
  bool directionChanged = false;
```

And for update method:

```
moveLeft = gameRef.joystick.direction == JoystickDirection.left;
moveRight = gameRef.joystick.direction == JoystickDirection.right;
moveTop = gameRef.joystick.direction == JoystickDirection.up;
moveDown = gameRef.joystick.direction == JoystickDirection.down;
```

now I am stuck in how or where should I put `directionChanged` to let player change clothes at the exact moment the player change to another direction, maybe something like:

```
    Future<void> update(double dt) async {
    if (moveRight) {
          directionChanged = true;
          changeClothes();
      }
    }

    changeClothes(){
      //clothe change method;
      directionChanged = false; 
    }
```

But then the joystick towards left, the `directionChanged` is already true, so cloth is still for right state.

thanks for any clue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save down the last joystick direction outside of the update loop and call the `changeClothes` method when the value isn't the same as it was in the last iteration.

```dart
  JoystickDirection lastDirection = JoystickDirection.idle;

  void update(double dt) {
    if(gameRef.joystick.direction != lastDirection) {
      changeClothes();
      lastDirection = gameRef.joystick.direction;
    }
  }
```

Comment: cool this works for me, I have same feeling for this but can not figure out how, thank you for this answer!